# On the problem of opening multiple threads to report insufficient memory resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

First of all, after using QT to create the 40th thread, the program reported an error that there were insufficient memory resources to execute the command. In this regard, I would like to ask how to solve this situation.
*The error message is as follows:*

```
Created consumer rdkafka#consumer-40.
QThread::start: Failed to create thread (insufficient memory resources to process this command.)
```

After this problem occurred, I looked up the information on the Internet and found that the problem was reported by windows's API. The specific location of the call is shown in this：

```
void QThread::start(Priority priority)
{
    Q_D(QThread);
    QMutexLocker locker(&d->mutex);

    if (d->isInFinish) {
        locker.unlock();
        wait();
        locker.relock();
    }

    if (d->running)
        return;
    ... ... // d指针配置

#ifndef Q_OS_WINRT
    ... ... // 注释
    d->handle = (Qt::HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, d->stackSize, QThreadPrivate::start,
                                            this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &(d->id));
#else // !Q_OS_WINRT
    d->handle = (Qt::HANDLE) CreateThread(NULL, d->stackSize, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)QThreadPrivate::start,
                                            this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(&d->id));
#endif // Q_OS_WINRT

    if (!d->handle) {
        qErrnoWarning(errno, "QThread::start: Failed to create thread");
        d->running = false;
        d->finished = true;
        return;
    }

    int prio;
    d->priority = priority;
    switch (d->priority) {
    ... ... // 线程优先级配置
    case InheritPriority:
    default:
        prio = GetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread());
        break;
    }

    if (!SetThreadPriority(d->handle, prio)) {
        qErrnoWarning("QThread::start: Failed to set thread priority");
    }

    if (ResumeThread(d->handle) == (DWORD) -1) {
        qErrnoWarning("QThread::start: Failed to resume new thread");
    }
}
```

But when I looked up the [Microsoft tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=msvc-170), the Microsoft tutorials did not give me the circumstances under which this error would occur and how to solve it, so I would like to get the answer to this question from you.

Comment: On what kind of system are you running this? Which CPU, which specific operating system, how much RAM, etc. Which compiler and C runtime are you using?

Comment: What is the `errno` value?

Comment: you are not getting a `std::system_error` from `std::thread` constructor?

Comment: @chris_se I run windows10 under x64 architecture, and the compiler is MinGW 7.3.0 32-bit for C++ with QT.

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @Eljay It seems that EACCES is given in the Microsoft tutorial.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No, because I directly called the API implemented by QT

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm sorry that I sent the picture directly and didn't give the text.

Comment: you can still [edit] the question. Select the code, ctrl+c to copy, then ctrl+v to paste it here

Comment: I suspect that on 32bit you just don't have enough virtual address space to start this amount of threads. I haven't done any 32bit development on Windows in years, so I can't say for sure, but I suspect that what you're running into an inherent limit here. (Note that you can start a lot more threads if you do nothing else than start threads, but address space fragmentation due to memory usage for other things will likely cause the practical limit to be much lower in your case.) Is there any way you can switch to 64bit?

Comment: MSDN says "`EACCES` if there are insufficient resources (such as memory)."  That's probably it then:  insufficient resources.

Comment: i don't know QThread, but if it doesn't report the error via exception then maybe now its time to switch to `std::thread`

Comment: `if (!d->handle)` is an invalid test of the returned value of `_beginthread`. Read the manual carefully.

Comment: @chris_se It seems that the current method can only upgrade the QT I use or switch to VS2022 for development, but this seems to be a bit too hard for me.

Comment: @Eljay So how did this mistake come out? I don't see an effective solution on MSDN.

Comment: @273K I know it is caused by the mistake here, so what I want to ask is, how can I solve this problem? thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Jack_joe1999: The solution is either to install more RAM into the machine, or create fewer threads

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Well, I might give it a try. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @MooingDuck  So if I want to keep so many threads and maintain the current RAM, is there no other solution?

Comment: @Jack_joe1999 What you could do to test this is write a simple test program that just starts threads in a loop in `main()` that do nothing (just sleep for a minute or so) and see how many threads you can create in that manner before that fails. If that number is larger than what you have in your case, then you are really running into 32bit address space issues (as I suspect that you are), and the only realistic solution (other than reducing the number of threads) is to actually switch to a 64bit compiler. (You're on a 64bit CPU anyway.)

Comment: @chris_se After I tried your method, I got the following conclusion:
A thread that simply sleeps for one minute can open more than 800 threads, which is much larger than my own. It seems that the only way is to upgrade the compiler, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: 40 threads by itself is not a big deal - even for a 32-bit process. There's something more going on here. How you done some cursory investigation in Task Manager to see the working set and active number of threads? I suspect you're hitting a 2GB working limit because of what's being doing in each thread....